# Proxy for installing Composer

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I want to install composer but i didn't know the proxy, or which proxy i'm supposed to use, please help
[composer setup wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwg3Z.png)

Edit:
i tried using `www.google.com:443` proxy

[using google proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz56b.png)

but it still gives me this error

[Composer Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl37g.png)

Edit : i try to leave the proxy empty and it give me this

[image: composer error]

here is the error code in text :

```
The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].

Script Output:
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Send of 129 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy? If you don't, or don't know, leave it empty.

Comment: You only fill in the proxy details if the machine where you're using composer has to use a proxy server to access the internet in general. If it doesn't, then leave those details blank.

Comment: okay i'll try to not use one ill update the question ASAP

Comment: i tried it and i still gives the same error, ill upload it to the question

Comment: Could be a firewall rule blocking it, or an SSL certificate problem perhaps

Comment: Please copy the error message from the dialog and paste it as text to your question to have the error message itself.

Comment: What is the PHP version on your computer? ([ref](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/issues/104))

Comment: my php version is php 8.0.10

Comment: ill update the question and include the error message as text

Comment: i still didnt know what's the solution, but i changed the machine i worked on and it works perfectly, im not suggesting to change machine if you encounter this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the SSL certification, using VPN worked

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the composer and running it. If you check the developer mode you need to leave "Use a proxy server to connect to the Internet" unchecked unless you have a proxy.

[Use a proxy server to connect to the Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRlWP.png)

If you already checked it and added any URL or IP to continue you need to remove the "http_proxy" from the environment.

In Windows just search for edit environment variables then delete the "http_proxy"

[See image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F329.png)

Comment: Thanks, sorry i forget to close the question, the problem was solved with VPN, apparently the machine i was using have an SSL Certification problem